# Different definitions of the EMF of a device - None of them applies to devices in a circuit

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, potential, voltage, definition

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromotive_force) gives two formal definitions of the electromotive force:

One in case of a closed loop, in which case the the EMF is supposed to be the path integral of the electric field (and all other forces effectively acting on charge carries) along that loop.

The other one in case of a device with isolated terminals, in which case the EMF is supposed to be the negative difference of the electrostatic potential (coulomb potential) created by the charges at the terminals.

None of these definitions deals with devices (like a resistor, or a capacitor, for example) that are part of an electric circuit.
Is there a definition that deals with an arbitrary devices inside an electric circuit (for example a resistor in an electric circuit which is neither short circuited, nor isolated)?

My proposition as a general formula to calculate the EMF along an electric device is to choose a path connecting the two terminals of the device along conductors inside the device, and then integrating along that path all forces that act on force carriers (all electric fields, conservative or rotational, lorentz-force, and effective chemical and thermal forces). Would that formula generalize the two definitions given at wikipedia?

Comment: Could the downvoter explain his downvote? I'd like to improve the question in case it is unclear / confusing.

Comment: FYI it wasn’t me

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia isn’t always the best source. The Hyperphysics website defines emf as the energy per unit charge (voltage) made available by an energy source, such as a battery or generator. With this definition the voltage across a resistor is not an emf since a resistor dissipates energy rather than makes energy available. The voltage across a charged capacitor, on the other hand, is an emf since it stores energy in its electric field.

Hope this helps.

Comment: To be honest, I don't think the hyperphysics website is the best source either (at least if you refer to this http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/hframe.html) website. For example, I find problematic that they don't discuss the problem of assigning a voltage to nonconservative electric fields. 
Additioinally, this http://www.physics.princeton.edu/~mcdonald/examples/volt.pdf princton article suggests (footnote 18 on page 10) that you can assign an emf also to a resistor.

Comment: @Quantumwhisp You can always find different definitions for things. But the mainstream definitions usually refer to it as a source of energy per unit charge. Here are just a few .https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/what-is-the-definition-of-emf.  588037/https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/electromotive%20forcehttps://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromotive_force https://www.britannica.com/science/electromotive-force. Some, like the following, say it can ALSO be defined as simply the voltage across an element.

Comment: @Quantumwhispvhttps://www.chegg.com/homework-help/definitions/electromotive-force-4

Comment: Suppose we are changing the magnetic flux through an open-circuit coil of wire. Would you say that there are two emfs, the Faraday's law emf and an emf in the opposite direction due to build-up of opposite charges on the end-regions of the wire? [I simply want to know your opinion.]

Comment: @BobD I am sorry, but none of the sources you link give a definition of EMF that is unambigous. Defining it as voltage is not sufficient, because there are many different meanings associated with voltage. The same goes for "potential", as it is not clear what potential is meant to be, or wether potential can be assigned to the situation in a meaningful way. 
Defining it as "energy gained per charge unit" isn't unambigous either, because it is not specified what should happen to the charge in order to gain energy.

Comment: @Phillip Wood That’s a good question and to be honest I’m not sure. I would think that In the first case we have some external (to the circuit) energy source providing the changing magnetic field (e.g. me moving a bar magnet in and out of a coil) creating the voltage  and in the second case a changing current in the circuit creating the voltage. What’s your opinion?

Comment: @Quantumwhisp Perhaps. But it seems to me that the emphasis is on a device that increases the potential, and I’l leave it at that. BTW regarding you proposition, when you say “conductors inside a device “ how would that apply to a capacitor?

Comment: @Bob D: I don't know how this should account for conductors inside a capacitor. I should followingly change alter my proposition (and I don't know how - yet). Can you explain what potential you mean, when you write "device that increases the potential" (electrostatic potential?). 
Additionally, can you say something about how exactly a particle is to gain energy from the device, specifically what path does it have to move along to gain the energy? "Through the device" makes no sense for a capacitor, while "from  terminal A to terminal B outside the device" makes no sense for an inductance.

Answer (score 0):

In view of the comments on my original answer, I offer this as an alternative.

In my working years I was an IEEE Surge Protective Devices (SPD) working group chairman. Although IEEE has many SPD standards, even after years of debate it was difficult to get agreement on just how to define the damn things.

Definitions aside, there is something different about a device where you can measure a voltage across its terminals when no current is flowing  (e.g., batteries, charged capacitors), and a device where you cannot measure a voltage across its terminals when no current is flowing (e.g., a resistor). Maybe you can call the voltage on the first an emf and on the latter as simply voltage. In which case, you might say that all emfs are voltages but not all voltages are emfs.  Or you might not.
And then there are devices that don’t fit neatly into one category or another (e.g. inductors. See @Phillip Woods comments)

I’m not asking you to agree with me, nor am I asking you to accept this “answer”. My only point is that getting agreement on a definition can be a futile exercise. In that spirit I wish you luck in developing your proposition.

Comment: It seems there is a misunderstanding about my last comment: The questions it contained were not meant to point out your answer is wrong. I accept your definition of the emf as the energy some unit of charge gets. The additional questions in that last comment were meant as actual questions that I have about that definition of yours, to make your answer more clear.

Comment: @Quantumwhisp I think you may be right. I will revise my original answer in an attempt to answer your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the meaning of electromotive force, in general, is line integral of all impressed forces acting on conduction charge, per unit charge, along some specified oriented path $\gamma$. The path can have open ends or be closed (which is the case when formulating famous physics laws, such as Faraday's law and Kirchhoff's second circuital law).

Formally,

$$
\mathscr{E}_\gamma = \int_{\gamma} \sum_n \mathbf E_n \cdot d\mathbf s,
$$

where $\mathbf E_n$ is the $n$-th impressed force per unit positive charge.

The important point here is that total EMF is a quantity specific for the oriented path. So if we are given two points, such as two terminals of an electronic device, and nothing else, there is no way to assign the points or the device unique EMF value.

That is, unless we adopt the tacit convention that when talking about circuit elements and EMF, we always mean the path that the electric current takes when going from one terminal to the other, in the chosen positive direction assigned to the element in the circuit analysis. Then, we can associate total EMF with any circuit element where current takes a definite path.

Another important point is that conservative electric field is usually not counted as impressed force when calculating EMF. One reason is that in an electrochemical cell that does not have its terminals connected into conductive path, conservative electric field forces cancel out the non-electric forces, so including them in the integral, we would get EMF zero, which is not what we want. Instead, in that case, we want emf to characterize the capacity of the cell to induce difference of potential, which is non-zero even when current is zero.

For a cell, we really have the definition

$$
\mathscr{E}_{cell} = \int_{\gamma_{-+}} \mathbf E' \cdot d\mathbf s
$$

where $\gamma_{-+}$ is the path going through the cell from the negative terminal to the positive terminal, and $\mathbf E'$ is the (macroscopically) non-electric force per unit positive charge (macroscopic force due to electrochemical effects on the conduction charge carriers in the electrolyte).

In other cases, such as when explaining the Kirchhoff second circuital law, it may be useful to temporarily redefine emf for circuit members to include the effect of the conservative electric field.

When the path is closed, and we talk about emf for  a closed path, this issue disappears, because circulation (line integral over closed path) of conservative field is zero.